# Read all active messages in azure service bus queue

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am new to azure service bus, I am supposed to push messages to a queue and then have a separate scheduled task that will read all active messages in this queue and bulk import them to sql
I tried this code before and it was working when I called it right after sending the message but now its not working within the separate scheduled task.
Any help why or what i can use to batch read the messages or that's not possible

```
queueClient = new QueueClient(conn, queuename, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

                var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
                {
                    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
                    AutoComplete = false
                };
                queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ReceiveMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);


public async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
        {
            messages.Add(message.Body.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
            await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
        }

        public Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know what library you are using to do this, but I recommend using the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/ nuget package, with it you can:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string queueName = "myqueue";
        var client = new ServiceBusClient("myconn");
        // create a processor that we can use to process the messages
        var processor = client.CreateProcessor(queueName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());
        // add handler to process messages
        processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
        // add handler to process any errors
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
        await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
        // Process messages for 5 minutes 
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        // stop processing 
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping the receiver...");
        await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped receiving messages");
    }
    private static Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs arg)
    {
        // Here you can catch errors;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        // Do something with the message .e.g deserialize it and insert to SQL
        try
        {
            BinaryData content = args.Message.Body;
            // Here you can use :
            string contentStr = content.ToString(); // This would be your data
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // If something goes wrong you should abandon the message
            await args.AbandonMessageAsync(args.Message);
        }
        await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
    }
}
```

This will process all messages until the time is up. This would be good for a scheduled task. If you want to stop after a specific number of messages have been processed, you can do an async loop and check if the number has been reached.

Comment: But what if I need the `contentStr` in the original function? I get in this case it's Main but what if this were an HTTP endpoint and I need to return a message body back to the caller?

Comment: It is usually not recommended to mix service bus with an HTTP endpoint, they work very differently. Service Bus is ASYNC, you should not wait for a response, like you do on HTTP. If you need to receive service bus messages on an HTTP client (browser for example) I recommend you take a look at something like SignalR, in that case you would receive the message and notify the client via a hub. Take a look at https://docs.particular.net/samples/near-realtime-clients/.